# How to get the controller which executed the presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidappear

I have UINavigationController with 3 views. In case the session with the server is expired then I launch(with the presentViewController) a second navigation controller which ask the user to login. If the login was successful then I dismiss the login navigation controller.
The problem is that I want to know which view in the navigation controller launched the login NC because i want to execute the viewDidAppear.
I tried to differentiate each view in the first NC by the title. I am thinking to get the title of the VC which presented the login NC and then get a pointer on it and execute the viewDidAppear.
This is my code in the login NC after a successful login:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    UINavigationController *viewConNav = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
    NSLog(@"%@",viewConNav.topViewController.title);

}];
```

but I get null. (Yes I set the title in the storyboard)

EDIT:
Actually I want to get the NC under the presented NC.

Comment: maybe self.presentingViewController helps...

Answer (score 0):

self.presentingViewController should have the right VC for you.

Instead, you should probably use:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: My question is how to get the VC which launched the login NC